# TestNG Parameter behaving inconsistently when executed multiple time

Tags: selenium, testng

I want to run multi-browser testing. For that, this is my testng.xml

```
<suite name="MultiBrowsreTest" parallel="tests">

    <test name="T1" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/> 
        <classes>
            <class name="com.core.My"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 

    <test name="T2" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/> 
        <classes>
            <class name="com.core.My"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

And Here is my Java program.

```
public class My {
        HH h ;
        @Test
        @Parameters("browser")
        public void my1(String browser){
                h = new HH();
                h.browser = browser;
                System.out.println("Browser: "+h.browser);
        }
}
```

When I run the program,it gives me different output all the time. i.e.

1: 
Browser: firefox
Browser: firefox

2:
Browser: chrome
Browser: firefox

3: 
Browser: chrome
Browser: chrome

4: 
Browser: firefox
Browser: chrome

Can someone please suggest me the solution so that I will get consistent result

Comment: how are you running the tests

Comment: [RESOLVED] : Actually this is working perfectly ok. After debugging for several hours O noticed that "h" in my application is static. Due to that, "h.browser" always shows one value. When I printed "browser" (which is a parameter), it was doing things as expected.

Answer (score 0):

parallel=true executes all tests at a time(in parallel) and hence whichever test it gets first is executed first.So, test order is not maintained and hence different outputs every time.

Make **parallel = none**, and it will follow the order as mentioned in testng xml.

```
<suite name="MultiBrowsreTest" parallel="none">
```

Comment: That doesnt explain the output - 

"Browser: chrome Browser: chrome"  or  " Browser: firefox Browser: firefox"

Comment: @Shamik, if we use parallel=true, testng may pickup T1 or T2 first and depending on this output will be printed. But if we make parallel=none, then T1 will always be executed first and then T2. I tried myself, its always T1 getting exected first and then T2.

Comment: right! But there if you put parallel equal to true. The output will either be chrome first then firefox or firefox then chrome . Agreed ?  since t1 and t2 has two different variables values ( as per the testng.xml he has provided). How does it explain. Firefox coming for both t1 and t2, i didn't understand that. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I executed his code many times but never got "Browser: chrome Browser: chrome" or " Browser: firefox Browser: firefox" as ouput.  May be wrong input in question.

Comment: Maybe. But the question says it got. Thats why i had asked how he was running

Comment: Vishal & Shamik, code is working as it should. My bad, "h" in my code is static which is leading to this problem.